# How to create an AppleScript or Command file to open a .jar file in a specific directory on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, shell, applescript

So I've been Googling and searching for literally 3 hours now for this solution. I used to have some files for this purpose but they have been deleted over the years.

Basically, I have a .jar file named RiD.jar located in: /Users/Mom/Desktop/RiD

The .jar was recently updated with changes that may allow the possibility of support for Mac OS X. I have been given the task of testing it in a Mac OS X environment.

I need to make a double-clickable file that will open the .jar file that can be added to the initial download (a .rar file containing a folder of all the included files, one of which being the RiD.jar) that will work universally for all Mac users.

Whether it uses AppleScript or something else, as long as it works I'm happy.

For the creation of any specific file type in your recommendation, please do me the favor of explaining what program would be used to make this file type and any other relevant information, as my OS X programming knowledge is limited.

Any help is appreciated and any questions you might have for me are more than welcome.

EDIT:

Here's a copy of what I get when I try and open it via the Terminal:

I have the newest version of Java included in the Mac App Store (e.g. Java 6 update 41).

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at Run.main(Run.java)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 4 more
```

EDIT: I just updated to Java 7 update 15 from the Oracle website because it is needed to run a Java applet in a browser that must work for the purpose of the original RiD.jar file. I still get the same error as from Java 6 update 41.

EDIT: I've spoken with the developer and he's removed the use of cmd when using OS X. I now have a slightly different error:

```
My-Computer:~ Mom$ cd /Users/Mom/Desktop/RiD
My-Computer:RiD Mom$ java -jar RiD.jar
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javaw": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at Run.main(Run.java)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 4 more
    enter code here
```

Comment: I'm very confused (which is probably why there are no answers). Your question seems to be about double clicking a script of some sort to run a .jar file. However, the stacktrace that you posted appears to an error from within the .jar file (I believe your jar file is trying to open cmd which doesn't exist on macs).

Comment: @supersam654
The developer is my boss, and he originally wrote the program for Windows, so that's probably why it has a mention of cmd. I know he has a built-in feature to make the javaw process automatically start in Realtime or High priority, so is it possible that could have something to do with it?

If another version of the .jar could be made to avoid this error, or a new version could be made to identify whether or not to use the cmd, this may be enough for the Developer to do so. I need to find the error though, or gather enough info for him for him to find it himself. Any advice helps!

Comment: Please elaborate on "find the error." Are you talking about the automatically execute the jar file with a script error or the stacktrace error (some internal part of the jar isn't working)?

Answer (score 0):

The error trace seems to show that the Java code calls "cmd", presumably to run some script. If this is the case, it will obviously not work on a Mac without some code change of the underlying Java code.

In general, to run JAR files on Mac requires that you install Java from Oracle. After that install, jar files should be associated to launch with Java on a normal double click.

UPDATE (to match updated question): The JAR file is trying to call the javaw, which is the console-less runtime for Java. Without seeing the code, I can't say why it's doing this, but it looks like a PATH error. In the terminal, try to write

```
which javaw
```

My guess is that it won't find the correct destination for javaw. The solution is either that you manuaylly edit your environment to include a path to javaw, if you can locate it, otherwise, easiest is to re-install Java from Oracle and see if the problem disappears.

It could also be that the script in the JAR file assumes an incorrect path for javaw, for example by assuming it to be located in a typical Windows path.

Comment: I've spoken with the developer and he's removed the use of cmd for OS X now.
Using the new version I get the error I just added to the main post